# PHP stopping tamper data in html form

Tags: php

Back story: Hey, so I've basically be at this for a few and couldn't quit find a fix for this, basically the user's been spoofing the value $price which is let's say $5 with the firefox addon tamper data they can change the $_POST value to whatever they wish usually $0.01, basically I'm trying to prevent this.

Code:

```
<?php
$price = "5.00";
?>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@email.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="AP">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php if($price != "5.00") { $price = "5.00"; echo $price; } else { echo $price; } ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="/ipn/ipn.php?user=<?php echo $username; ?>"index.php?thank=yes">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="index.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="pp" value="Buy Subscription" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pp'])) {
if($price != "5.00") {
$price = "5.00";
echo $price . " DEBUG: SCAMMER";
} else {
echo $price . " nothing was found";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this form pointing to PayPal? If yes, you will never be able to prevent tampering, because the form never touches your server. But doesn't the IPN callback script receive the amount paid? That's where a check could and should happen.

Comment: Are you using the same page to create the form as you use to submit the form?

Comment: Why are you using the price from the form, instead of looking the price up based on the product?

Comment: @crush he appears to be using [PayPal's standard payments form](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/) or something similar.

Comment: So, shouldn't he be verifying if they paid the proper amount at his notify_url? `/ipn/ipn.php?user=<?php echo $username; ?>"index.php`

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm using the PayPal IPN (/ipn/ipn.php Would you like that as well?).

Comment: @user3258734 That's where you should be validating the price they paid.

Comment: The [`mc_gross` variable](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) will contain the amount paid in your ipn.php. Never worked with IPN but I guess that's where any validation should happen.

Comment: @Pekka웃 so I'm guessing basically what I do is if(mc_gross['50.99'] !=) { mc_gross['50.99']; }

Comment: @user that won't work (apart from being syntactically incorrect?) You need to know what `mc_gross` is supposed to be, and that info needs to come from somewhere else than the user's form. I guess what one would typically do is have a database table with transactions, with a column showing the expected value, and another having a random, unique ID that you can use to access the correct entry in the IPN file. Alternatively, hard-code expected prices in your script

Comment: @Pekka웃 Right so basically you're saying $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'] if ($payment_account != "50.99") {
$payment_amount = "50.99";
} else {
$payment_amount = "50.99";
} Won't work because I can't externally do that I need to possibly ban the user from the database instead basically?

Comment: @user you can't change the amount the user sent you through PayPal. You can only deny to provide them the download or service they didn't pay for in full (or ban them or whatever). Not sure whether there is any way to file a complaint about this kind of thing with PayPal

Comment: @Pekka웃 right right right so basically what I do is if ($amount != "50.99") { //deny payment } in the IPN, what's the function to deny a paypal transaction?

Comment: I don't think you can deny it. Maybe you can refund it? Not sure. You'd likely have to start a completely new transaction for that and I don't know which API handles that. You may need to handle that part manually

Comment: Related: [How to deny payment via PayPal IPN?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2838255)

Comment: @Pekka웃 if ($amount != "50.99") { 
 $scammer = $odb ->prepare("UPDATE `users` DELETE WHERE `username` = '$usernameget'");
 $scammer ->execute();
} Think that'll work? ;)

Comment: @user probably - but you'd trace all the evidence of the scammer's misdeeds. Not sure whether you'd want that

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sorry, please rephrase that not sure what you mean by that and also, this doesn't work & I did declare $amount as mc_gross, guessing there's a problem with my delete code? or what?

Comment: You'll have to debug your delete code, there is no way to tell from here what the problem with it could be, there are many things that could fail. Re deleting, I mean you may not want to remove evidence of the scammy user from your database. You may want to handle cases like this manually, e.g. by sending yourself an automated warning E-Mail and deleting the user after you have told them you are kicking them out (or whatever.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I see yeah, well I don't really want to even keep their information i'll just log it into a text file, but mhm if you could debug my code that'll be great I'm just panicing currently because my account got limited for having 3 charge backs open -_-, even though they received exactly what they wanted & charge backed as unauthorized.

Comment: I'm dealing with a huge pile of work myself right now, sorry... if you call the IPN script manually and fake the payment-related values, you should be able to see the error messages that you need to fix. It's literally impossible to tell from here what the problem with the code is, one needs to see what it outputs

Comment: @Pekka웃 Tested this & it worked thanks so much Pekka! f ($payment_amount != "5.00") {
 $noty = $odb ->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET paid=0 WHERE `username` = '$usernameget'");
 $noty ->execute();
 $scammer = $odb ->prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$usernameget'");
 $scammer ->execute();
$file2 = 'scammers.txt';
    $buffer2 = date('d-m-Y') . ' We got a scammer!';
    if (file_exists($file2)) {
            $buffer2 = file_get_contents($file) . "\n" . $buffer2;
    }
    $success2 = file_put_contents($file2, $buffer2);
}

Comment: @Pekka웃 Hoping now this will actually work with a legitimate sale, do you think it will?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't know whether it'll work though - this kind of stuff needs to be tested/debugged, there is no way to tell from just the code.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Mhm, alright if you would like answer with the code I posted & i'll accept it as a answer so you get reputation ;)

Comment: I posted a generic answer, I guess that should be informative enough for future readers!

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks again Pekka, you're definitely one of the most HQ users on this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't influence this - the form is sent directly to PayPal, and never touches your server.

You should check in the IPN notification PHP script whether the amount you received matches the amount you are expecting, and take whatever steps necessary if it doesn't.